# Knockout foreach to generate dynamically data bound items

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

Here is the code i am trying to get working,

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: currentStepCollection()">
    <li id="ap-li1" class="wizar-li" data-bind="css: { active: id == currentStep().id }">
        <span class="step" data-bind="text: id"></span>
        <span class="title" data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to iterate an observableArray and each list item needs to apply "active" style if the "id" attribute of the iterating item equals `currentStep().id` knockout observable. `currentStep()` is an observable in the View Model.

I am getting the following error,

> knockout-3.4.0.debug.js:3326 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return currentStepCollection() }"
>   Message: Unable to process binding "css: function (){return { complete:1 < currentStep().id,active:1 == currentStep().id} }"
>   Message: currentStep is not defined

Is it possible to do this with knockout?

When i try following simplified version,

It just set the `data-bind="css: { active: id == 1}"` where I am expecting 1 == 1, 2 == 1, 3 == 1 for each iteration.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You'll need to show your code for us to be able to help, preferably an [mcve]. The problem will very likely be that `currentStep` is not defined on the objects inside the `currentStepCollection`, but suggesting a solution is near impossible without seeing the code.

Comment: Also, amy you forget to add $root prefix: `active: id == $root.currentStep().id`

Comment: $root did the trick. Thanks.